# the asp.net core version 7.0 dose not showing up

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

i installed visual studio 2019 for make asp.net core project and only when creating web application project it shows me only 2.1 as target version.
[like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGOhl.png)

i tried to update visual studiocode packages and i installed .net sdk 7.0 and runtime 7.0 and still the same problem only ver 2.1 is showing up.

[this is the installed version for runtime and sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7CdI.png)

is there any thing i can do to make it show 7.0 version as target framework for new projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Visual Studio 2022. The 2019 doesn't support .NET 6 and above as you can read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1182